# Maximal unramified subextension at one prime

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of algebraic number fields with Galois group $G$, $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime of $K$ and $\mathfrak{q}_1,...,\mathfrak{q}_m$ be the primes of $L$ lying over $K$. Then we have the interia subgroups $I_{\mathfrak{q}_i/\mathfrak{p}}$ of $G$, then we can define the subgroup $H$ of $G$ generated by these $I_{\mathfrak{q}_i/q}$.

Then I guess that $L^H$ is the maximal unramified subextension of $L$ at $\mathfrak{p}$, where maximality means that if $M$ is any subextension which is unramified at $\mathfrak{p}$, then $M$ is contained in $L^H$.

Is my guess right? If not, I hope someone could explain how we can construct the maximal unramified subextension at one prime. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

Let $F$ an intermediate field then the exponent $e((q_j\cap O_F)/p)$ of $q_j\cap O_F$ in $pO_F$ is $1$ iff $$|I(q_j/p)|=e(q_j/p)=e(q_j/(q_j\cap O_F))=|I(q_j/(q_j\cap O_F))|$$ iff $I(q_j/p)=I(q_j/(q_j\cap O_F))$ iff $F$ is fixed by $I(q_j/p)$.

Thus $p$ is unramified in $O_F$ iff all the $e((q_j\cap O_F)/p)=1$ iff $F$ is fixed by all the $I(q_j/p)$.

Comment: Thanks. I use this to see how to define local Artin L function at these ramified primes.